# BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 16.04 using ruby-build 20170726-2-g254728e)

Tags: software-installation, ruby

I'm new to Ubuntu. I want to install ruby using `rbenv` (`rbenv install 2.2.1`) But I get the error:

```
BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 16.04 using ruby-build 20170726-2-g254728e)
```

Here is the script I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Installing rbenv using a Installer

```
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential \
                     libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 \
                     libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev \
                     python-software-properties libffi-dev

cd
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL
rbenv install 2.2.1
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hello, did you fix the issue. I have the same issue there. I successfully installed Ruby 2.4.0 but need 2.2.4 to recover a project already created.

Comment: I could not install version 2.2.1, so at the end I installed version 2.3.0

Comment: Could you post that as an answer to your question, with more details if possible (even just saying that the procedure described in your question *did* work for the other version), to help future visitors?